# JAXB compiler is binding xs:boolean to Java boolean instead of Boolean wrapper class

Tags: java, jaxb, jaxb2-maven-plugin

I'm using jaxb2-maven-plugin ver 1.5 to generate Java classes from XSD in my project. My XSD looks like:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="ClientRQ">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>   
        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="ClientID" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
        <xs:element type="xs:boolean" name="Complimentary" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/> 
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="Version"/>
      <xs:attribute type="xs:dateTime" name="TimeStamp"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

After deserialization to Java Class I receive **boolean complimentary** fild but I need to have **Boolean**. **I can not edit XSD**, because it is public. Does anybody know how to solve this issue without changing the scheme?

Answer (score 1):

`jaxb2-maven-plugin` version 1.5 is old. Update to latest and see if you still have this issue.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason of `boolean` type, is the fact that you defined the field `Complimentary` as non-optional, with `minOccurs=1` JAXB always creates the field with the primitive type since it cannot be null, just try to use `minOccurs=0` and you'd see the difference.

To control this behaviour use `<jxb:globalBindings optionalProperty="wrapper">` in your bindings document.